# How can I link function parameter types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object with values of type `string` and `number`:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I have a function that changes the object with one parameter as the field index, and the other as the field value:

```
const person = {name: "Fred", age: "30"};

const changePerson = (index: keyof Person, value: string | number): void => {
  person[index] = value;
}
```

The problem is that, as TypeScript sees it, `index` can be "name" and `value` can be a number, but that would never happen. I'm not sure how to link `index` and `value` to tell TypeScript that the types are linked in a specific way.

Can anyone help?

I was able to get rid of the errors by using a case statement but that would not be transpiled out as TypeScript normally would:

```
const changePerson = (index: keyof Person, value: string | number): void => {
  switch(index) {
    case "name":
      person[index] = value as string;
      break;

    default:
      person[index] = value as number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with generics:
`<T extends keyof Person>(index: T, value: Person[T]): void`

This basically tells the type system that the second parameter has to be whatever the first one points to on the type.

The full example on [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzGlxM1kCuFARtDZEAvsWIIc9ZAAdMOWuijZcAXnzkqtAEQAxKBAAm2gDTJO3AMwAGEcIlSwyBAAs4ILkpXJ1AHgAqyBAAHpAghhjIANYQAJ5YMGjyIAB8ABSghiHU-mYAbnAANjzcXjgA2v4AugCUtHlYwIY+KfjsssnlmSFVPsgFxRDCYkTEAPRjyADyANISbh4QZSBp2poQpsjacBiGMNo19kQTyADCWBQywIVwYMA4QVBQWFDz7p7Jq+ubAEyHxEA)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!